# Issue with Linkedin integration using socialauth in android

Tags: android, linkedin-api, socialauth

I had implmented linkedin integartion in my android app using socialauth a year ago. It was working fine till few days back. Now it gives following error:

*"org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthConfigurationException: Application keys are not correct. The server running the application should be same that was registered to get the keys.*"

Tried using following default keys also.

```
api.linkedin.com.consumer_key = bh82t52rdos6
api.linkedin.com.consumer_secret = zQ1LLrGbhDZ36fH8
```

Getting same error for keys of app generated previously, default app keys and for fresh created app.

Any idea why it is happening? Is there any change in linkedin APIs?

**Libs included** : socialauth-4.4.jar, socialauth-android-3.2.jar.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the change in the Linked in developer program.
Changes are mentioned here https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition.

You getting this error because the default scope setting in the `r_fullprofile` which is as part of the change no longer available.

So to apply this changes in the socialauth API you should pass the scope permission as `<prop key="api.linkedin.com.custom_permissions">r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress</prop>`

Comment: Same configuration is required for Android by adding "api.linkedin.com.custom_permissions = r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress" to the "oath_consumer.properties" file.

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin have updated their Scope for API , they have updated their APIs link:https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:
Basic Profile Fields
Location Fields
Position Fields

These fields are not

Full Profile Fields
Contact Info Fields
Company Fields
Publication Fields
Patent Fields
Language Fields
Skill Fields
Certification Fields
Course Fields
Education Fields
Volunteer Fields
Recommendation Fields.

Additionally 
 only these Profile API — /v1/people/~ Share API — /v1/people/~/shares Companies API — /v1/companies/{id} will work.

Check your scope.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn locked many parts of its APIs on May 12, 2015 according to https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Since you're using the socialauth library, you will have to wait for its developers to push a new version. :(

Answer (score 0):

Downloading 4.9 library solves this issue
You can get the jar from Maven directly:
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/brickred/socialauth/4.9/socialauth-4.9.jar