# Integrate linkedin in android app using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, linkedin-api

I have an existing app with linkedin integrated via social auth. Since linkedin APIs have changed recently, it no longer works. So I tried to integrate it again from scratch.
I downloaded android sdk from [linkedin site](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk). Upon extracting it has linkedin sdk and samples in as Android Studio projects.

Any idea how to integrate it in eclipse?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**
I have run sample given with sdk in eclipse. It gives error

> either bundle id or package name / hash are invalid unknown malformed

I am not able to find where to put my app's client key and id in eclipse sample project.
Any idea about this?

Comment: what kind of error u r getting post logcat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212290/issue-with-linkedin-integration-using-socialauth-in-android
This contains error logs and issues with social auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer need not use client id and secret in code. Linkedin manages on basis of project package name and key hash given in project app generated on linkedin dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

***First off all you have to generate signed APK as per the*** [*Documentation*](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk)

> Try to check that the release key hash value of the keystore you used
>   to sign the APK is correctly listed in the "Android Package Names and
>   Hashes" field of your LinkedIn application's configuration as
>   described in the [documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk):

***Generating a release key hash value***

> To generate a release key hash value, use the following command:
>
> ```
> keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
> ```

***Configure the values***

> In the "Android Package Names and Hashes" field of your LinkedIn
>   application's configuration, provide one or more values in the
>   following comma-separated format:
>
> ```
> Android.Package.Name,Key-Hash-Value
> ```

***The LinkedIn API considering security of the application.we must follow code obfuscation also while integrating.***